# How to include ext-js calendar in jsp?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am new to EXT JS environment. I am working on a dynamic java project in eclipse indigo where i want to use ext-js calendar in one of my jsp.I saw the EXT_JS calendar demo from downloaded 'ext-4.1.1' sdk(index.html file in ext-4.1.1a\examples\calendar).

I want to create a .js file as like ext-js calendar page. So for that i followed the path given in 
http://loianegroner.com/2010/11/spket-setting-up-eclipse-ide-for-ext-js-and-jquery-development/   to integrate ext-js in eclipse.

But now when i copy index.html to my webcontent folder then it is not working(Originally it is showing nothing). But when i copy the entire ext-js source code to my workspace web content then running the index.html file in example/calendar folder of ext-4.1.1a giving me required result.But I don't think this as a solution.

I could not find any way also how to start to do my task.
So Pls anybody help me here...

Regards : 
Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nothing shows up on the screen, it is commonly a case where the ExtJS library isn't loaded. Without seeing the code, it's hard to pinpoint the issue.

Using Chrome Dev tools or Firebug for Firefox, take a look at the console and/or network output.

The files you're looking for will be included in the `<head>` section of your `index.html`. There should be `ext-all.js` or possibly `ext-all-debug.js` at a minimum, plus the style sheets.

If this is your issue, then you need to include the proper paths to the ExtJS library. This can be the local installation, or you can use a CDN. For example:

`<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Corey... I got it..There was a path issue for which it was not loading the ExtJs library.I made all those files local to my applicatio0n and now it is working fine.